# Как предотвратить засыпание компьютера в .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть программа. В фоновых потоках выполняются разные действия и выводят данные на форму. Но компьютер может перейти в ждущий/спящий режим, тогда программа перестает работать. Как программно заставит компьютер не спать? У uTorrent есть такая функция в настройках, хотелось бы узнать как это осуществить из C# (.NET)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используя функцию WinAPI [SetThreadExecutionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[How to prevent Windows from entering idle state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302185/how-to-prevent-windows-from-entering-idle-state)